# How to pass system variable with normal variable to call java program in command line batch script

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line

```
java -cp %EPM_JAVA_CLASSPATH% -DEPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE=%1 -DHFM_CLUSTER=%2 -DHFM_APPLICATION=%3 runConsoltesting %4 %5 %6 %7
```

When i try to access 5th argument it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at runConsoltesting.main(runConsoltesting.java:42)
```

It takes only arguments upto class name

Comment: Try quoting all the `%` arguments.

Comment: You only pass **four** arguments to the main class: `%4 %5 %6 %7` (if nonempty) will be `args[0] args[1] args[2] args[3]` respectively. The `-Dname=value` _before_ the classname are arguments and more exactly options _to the JVM but not to the main class_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever given after main class runConsoltesting are main method arguments which are totally 4 (%4,%5,%6,%7). So you are getting ArrayOutOfBoundException when you try to access fifth element.

%1, %2 and %3 are JVM arguments and NOT java main method arguments. So these can be read in code as below.

System.getProperty(String property), here property is name of your -D argument.

For example, System.getProperty("EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE") will return the value which is set for place of %1.